# Read from JSON where URL contains funny character

Tags: r, json, urlencode, rjsonio

I am trying to read from an API where the URL contains a non-standard latin character in R, but am getting an error. Similar URLs without a funny character work fine.

I get following error

```
> RJSONIO::fromJSON("https://api-prod.footballindex.co.uk/exchange-orders/market-depth/kylian-mbappé")
Error in file(con, "r") : cannot open the connection
```

Standard characters work fine

```
res <- RJSONIO::fromJSON("https://api-prod.footballindex.co.uk/exchange-orders/market-depth/neymar")
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is more of an url-encoding problem than an R or JSON one.
But this should work:

```
RJSONIO::fromJSON("https://api-prod.footballindex.co.uk/exchange-orders/market-depth/kylian-mbapp%C3%A9")
```

This [link](https://www.key-shortcut.com/en/character-tables/ascii-url-encoding/) could also help you for theoretical background information and this [one](https://www.urlencoder.org/) for practical conversions.

You can also use `utils::URLencode` to do the conversion within R:

```
utils::URLencode("https://api-prod.footballindex.co.uk/exchange-orders/market-depth/kylian-mbappé")
[1] "https://api-prod.footballindex.co.uk/exchange-orders/market-depth/kylian-mbapp%C3%A9"
```

Comment: Thanks so much, however any idea why I get this?
 ```> URLencode('é')
[1] "%E9"``` rather than %C3%A9 like you do? Presumably a setting

Comment: It depends on the character-set: hhttps://www.w3schools.com/tags/ref_urlencode.asp
Windows-1252 <> UTF-8